# YAML string with leading white space

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to place some whitespace at the start of a string, like so:

```
- sbSecId: 4
  title: '  VideoJS'
  link: /examples/video/instream/videojs/pb-ve-videojs.html
  isLastSubSectionItem: 0
  isHeader: 0
  isSectionHeader: 0
  sectionTitle: 
  subgroup: 1
```

this is for a site being generated by Jekyll. I'm using Liquid to make an array of the yml file, looping through the array and displaying the `title` key's value like so:

```
{{thisSubItem.title}}
```

despite having the key value in quotes the whitespace is being deleted. Is this a Jekyll thing? How can I get the whitespace to be retained?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Jekyll thing this html that strips unnecessary spaces.

Here you can use CSS rule

```
<span style="white-space: pre;">{{thisSubItem.title}}</span>
```

Or by replacing spaces by non-breaking spaces

```
{% assign preserved_ws = thisSubItem.title | replace: " ", "&nbsp;" %}
{{ preserved_ws }}
```

Nevertheless, if it's only a presentation matter, you must get rid of spaces and go with CSS margins.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you could leave the spaces out of the string and have it in the layout or wherever the value is being rendered. You could remove the whitespace from the string and wouldn't need to worry about remembering to keep the whitespace consistent.

```
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; {{thisSubItem.title}}
```